# What's CTSubscriber (and how to use it) on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, core-telephony

On iOS 7, `CTSubscriber` was added to the `CoreTelephony` framework. There is no documentation available, only its header file:

```
/*
 * CTSubscriberTokenRefreshed
 *
 * Description:
 *     The name of the NSNotification sent when the carrier token is available.
 */
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTSubscriberTokenRefreshed  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);

CORETELEPHONY_CLASS_AVAILABLE(7_0)
@interface CTSubscriber : NSObject

/*
 * carrierToken
 *
 * Description:
 *     A data blob containing authorization information about the subscriber.
 *
 *     May return nil if no token is available.
 */
@property (nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSData* carrierToken  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);

@end
```

Also, on [What's new on iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1), this is mentioned:

> The Core Telephony framework (`CoreTelephony.framework`) lets you get information about the type of radio technology in use by the device. **Apps developed in conjunction with a carrier can also authenticate against a particular subscriber for that carrier**.

I think that `CTSubscriber` is related to the bold part of the text. However, I haven't found anything related on how this happens.

I have tried to use the following code (added to `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) to experiment with this API, but the notification is never fired and `carrierToken` returns `nil`:

```
CTSubscriber *subscriber =  [CTSubscriberInfo subscriber];
NSLog(@"%@", subscriber.carrierToken);

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:CTSubscriberTokenRefreshed object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSLog(@"==========");
    NSLog(@"%@", note);
    NSLog(@"%@", subscriber.carrierToken);
}];
```

So, I have the following questions:

- What exactly (*"authorization information"*) does `carrierToken` return and how to make it not `nil`?
- How does Apple know if your app is *"developed in conjunction with a carrier"*?
- Is this how Evernote is giving 1 year of premium account to Telefonica users (http://blog.evernote.com/blog/2013/08/13/evernote-and-telefonica-announce-global-partnership/)? (Probably not, since the information they need can be obtained on `CTCarrier`)

Comment: please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961271/coretelephony-framework-ios-7

Comment: This does not answer my questions. It's only said that some methods are private (the ones I posted are public) and the information I posted (documentation and header) are there too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the same question in the developer forums and got this reply :

`You should escalate this via the carrier you're working with, who can in turn escalate it to their contact at Apple.`

Link to the thread: https://devforums.apple.com/message/934226#934226

Comment: It seems that this is the better answer someone can get. Just in case, I'll wait a little before giving the bounty.

Comment: The link does not work anymore ..
Is there any documentation or samples on how to use it in more details ?

Answer (score -1):

The reason you can’t find any documentation is because much of Core Telephony consists of private APIs. Consequently, there isn’t any way to access the SIM card from an app published on the App Store. A jailbroken device is, of course, another story, but in that case you’re pretty much on your own.

Edit:

The Core Telephony framework (CoreTelephony.framework) lets you get
information about the type of radio technology in use by the device.
Apps developed in conjunction with a carrier can also authenticate
against a particular subscriber for that carrier.

Comment: So why did Apple made the methods I mentioned public?

Comment: I know that. It's mentioned on my question. What I want to know is how "Apps developed in conjunction with a carrier can also authenticate against a particular subscriber for that carrier".