# What is AppleBasebandManager framework in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

> In iOS there are two kinds of frameworks: public frameworks and
>   private frameworks. Public frameworks are allowed to be used in App
>   Store apps. Private frameworks are intended to be used only by Apple's
>   apps, and are more unstable against firmware changes, but many of the
>   interesting features are in the private frameworks.

That came from the following page:

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki//System/Library/Frameworks

On that page, I also see something called the AppleBasebandManager framework, but it supports only iOS 7.
**What is the AppleBasebandManager framework in iOS 7**?

If anybody know about this give details.

Comment: Seems to be intertwined with CoreTelephony. See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961271/coretelephony-framework-ios-7

Comment: Have you seen its [symbols list?](https://github.com/limneos/classdump-dyld/blob/master/iphoneheaders/iOS7.0.3/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleBasebandManager.framework/AppleBasebandManager-Symbols.h)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is an undocumented private framework, we can’t know for sure what its role is. From the name, I would assume Apple uses it to manage ‘baseband’ operations. A [Google search for ‘iPhone baseband’](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=iphone%20baseband) is informative:

> A baseband processor is a device in a network interface that manages all the radio functions (all functions that require an antenna). This may not include Wi-Fi and/or Bluetooth.

— [*Baseband processor*, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseband_processor):

> iPhone baseband is essentially the cellular modem firmware that is on your iPhone.

— [*What is iPhone Baseband?*, OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/09/what-is-iphone-baseband/)

So I would assume `AppleBasebandManager` is an interface to the mobile networking stack.

Answer (score 0):

Baseband is the firmware of the iPhone's cellular radio hardware (or modem). `AppleBasebandManager` has everything related to it's functionality.

Look at this header file and you can get a rough idea about what it does

[AppleBasebandManager-Symbols.h](https://github.com/limneos/classdump-dyld/blob/master/iphoneheaders/iOS7.0.3/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleBasebandManager.framework/AppleBasebandManager-Symbols.h)