# Xamarin forms callkit integration

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop a xamarin forms app in which user can make call
(Navigate to dialer) from taping on number showed on app.In android I accomplished this through dependency service.But in ios I am stuck.I heard about callkit.I saw the documentation of it in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/callkit?tabs=windows. But how can I actually implement on this in my App? I added all the classes in that document to my app.But how I can make the call from xamal.cs to the ios specified code? By using Dependency service?

**Edit**: I know how to navigate app to dialer or phone app. Why I am using callkit is I want to get the call duartion.

**I created an Instance**

```
 public interface IosCallerDialer
    {
        void StartCall();
    }
```

**Implementation on ios**

```
class IosCallDial: IosCallerDialer
    {
        private CXCallController CallController = new CXCallController();


        private void SendTransactionRequest(CXTransaction transaction)
        {
            // Send request to call controller
            CallController.RequestTransaction(transaction, (error) => {
                // Was there an error?
                if (error == null)
                {
                    // No, report success
                    Console.WriteLine("Transaction request sent successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Yes, report error
                    Console.WriteLine("Error requesting transaction: {0}", error);
                }
            });
        }

        public void StartCall()
        {
            // Build call action
            string contact = "8547085532";
            var handle = new CXHandle(CXHandleType.Generic, contact);
            var startCallAction = new CXStartCallAction(new NSUuid(), handle);

            // Create transaction
            var transaction = new CXTransaction(startCallAction);

            // Inform system of call request
            SendTransactionRequest(transaction);
        }


    }
```

**My xaml.cs**

```
async void btnCall_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {        
       DependencyService.Get<IosCallerDialer>().StartCall();      
    }
```

Apart this I added all the classes defined in the document.I want only outgoing call. Is this proper way? I cant find any tutorials regarding callkit on xamarin. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: I understand Callkit only for voip. So is there any other workaround like starting a timer when moves to phone app and stop timer when returns to app? Is it possible? Please provide any insights.

Comment: have you read the docs for CallKit?  It is used for VOIP integration, not for general integration with the phone app.

Comment: @Jason oh..so is there any other way to get the call duration of last call in ios?

Comment: I doubt it.  iOS doesn't really expose any APIs that have this kind of data

Comment: @Jason if user open the phone app and after calling user will return to app.Can I calculate the app inactive time or something?

Comment: Have you tried the [CTCallCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/coretelephony.ctcallcenter?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)? See here: [How to detect call incoming programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24930697/10539446).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Hi, I want the time when outgoing call ends.

Comment: There are call states you can detect and I wonder if you can get the call duration by calculate the time from start to end.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT can you help me to implement this on my forms app? Currently placing call by xamarin.essential.  How can I integrate this call end detection? Can you help me

Comment: @AndroDevil Use a [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I know how to use messaging centre.Where I am stuck is how to implement this on ios part. ie; Appdelegate part

Comment: Ok, let me try it on my side.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Then It will be a huge help brother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the code below to detect the state of incoming call.

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //

   public CTCallCenter c { get; set; }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        c = new CTCallCenter();

        c.CallEventHandler = delegate (CTCall call)
        {

            if (call.CallState == call.StateIncoming)
            {
                //start the timer 
            }
            else if (call.CallState == call.StateDialing)
            {

            }
            else if (call.CallState == call.StateConnected)
            {

            }
            else if(call.CallState == call.StateDisconnected)
            {
                //end the timer 
                //use messagecenter to send duartion

                 MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(new Object(), "Hi");

            }

        };

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
}
```

And any Where in Xamarin.forms:

```
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "Hi", (sender) => {
        // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent

        Console.WriteLine("hihihi");
    });
```

Note: I haven't test it on my side yet as I don't have enough device. You can test it and let me know if it works.

Comment: @AndroDevil Try it on your side and it is easy. I am not able to test it right now.

Comment: How to implement message center  inside app delelate? Can you please include that in above answer?

Comment: Bro thanks. Will apple block my app at appstore if i use this?

Comment: @AndroDevil I don't think apple will reject this. It's an api from CoreTelephony.