# Flutter: Get number incoming call

Tags: flutter

I've been studying Flutter and I'm really enjoying it.

I want to make an application that identifies the phone number when receiving a call, is this possible in Flutter?

Thanks

Comment: Glad you are enjoying flutter! In order for us to help you we need more information such as example code and more description about your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems possible though also quite difficult. There isn't official support for this and there aren't any packages that do what you need. The only way that I see is to create platform-specific implementations and use platform channels.

[Possible android implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device)

[Possible iOS implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535355/how-to-detect-call-incoming-programmatically)

[Platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)