# iOS detect incoming miss call in background

Tags: ios

How do I detect incoming miss call in iOS, in background?
I used CTCallCenter but it is only has state disconnected. So I can't distinguish if call was rejected by user or by remote.

I look CTCall.h, seem it's impossible:

```
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTCallStateDialing  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTCallStateIncoming  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTCallStateConnected  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTCallStateDisconnected  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_4_0);
```

Comment: Seems there is nothing in CoreTelephony helping you with that task. Despite its original documentation (from iOS4), there is a small update which seems to be hardly documented; see [iOS6 to iOS7 changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013203) (search for Core Telephony) and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20334400/91282.

Comment: Thanks Till. I'm reading it.